# VS2013 - Nuget - Installing Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2 gives error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, google-api, nuget, google-api-dotnet-client

Peace be upon You,

I have VS2013 Ultimate, I tried to install Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2 using Package manager console with this command as stated [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2/1.7.0.7-beta)

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2 -Pre
```

and I got these results:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Google.Apis (≥ 1.7.0-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Google.Apis.Core (≥ 1.7.0-beta)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.0.19)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async (≥ 1.0.16)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.1.10)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Zlib.Portable (≥ 1.9.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'log4net (≥ 2.0.0)'.
Install-Package : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2 -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

It seems to be the log4net package, although I installed it separately!

Answer (score 0):

It is not log4net. Looks like google.apis.datastore.v1beta2.1.7.0.7 is not available on nuget:

https://az320820.vo.msecnd.net/packages/google.apis.datastore.v1beta2.1.7.0.7-beta.nupkg throws 404 The specified blob does not exist, so it looks like an issue on nuget site. You should report it to package owners or nuget team.

Comment: Can you please install v1.7.0.6? It should work. We are aware of this issue and working to fix it.